# UIView as a Bottom ToolBar in UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitoolbar

I want to use A **View** as a Bottom **ToolBar**. How can I implement this idea . Anyone have any suggestion or any demo?

Screen shot of my view where i want this toolbar
[image]

Comment: Your requirement is not very clear. Could you give us more information?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean either. Do you just want a view at the bottom of the screen where you can put different action-elements like buttons or what?

Comment: That image isn't really telling anything. Whats the context, where is it placed in relation to the rest of the screen

Comment: @TMob check it out i just added full image.

Comment: @HarrisonXi check it again added image

Comment: If you do decide to go with the UIView as the bottom toolbar, I would suggest getting rid of that constraint to the top and just making the constraint be to the bottom. Also add a height constraint.  That will be best for different height sizes on devices.  Making your own UIView as the bottom toolbar is fine, it gives you some freedom to customize it however you want.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve something like this, is to just add a UIView at the bottom of your view (e.g. in storyboard) and add the items you want to it. 
You'd have to resize the scrollable content of your app, so that it doesn't overlap with the bottom bar.

At last you need to hook up actions to the items that you placed inside the new UIView.

Comment: I add UIView and items in it but  not showing any this .

Comment: How do you add it? Are you working with storyboards? If so, please add a screenshot of your view in the storyboard

Comment: I'm sorry, I think you got me wrong. Please take a screenshot of your storyboard, showing the View where you want the toolbar and add the screenshot to your stackoverflow-question

Comment: This looks actually pretty good. And it doens't appear at all? What does it look like, when you run it? Is it maybe hidden?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your singleton class -

in .h file

```
typedef void(^btnClick) (id sender);
@property (nonatomic,strong) btnClick pClickAction;
```

in .m file

```
- (void)addViewIn:(UIViewController*)controller With:(void(^)(id sender))btnClickBlock
{
    view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, controller.view.frame.size.height-50, controller.view.frame.size.width, 50)];

    btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, controller.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
    btn.tag = 1233;
    UIImage *Img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"add image"];
    [btn setImage:Img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn  addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    _pClickAction = btnClickBlock;
    [view addSubview:btn];

    //same like button you can add image nd label as your requirement
    [controller.view addSubview:view];
}
```

if you want to add view in view controller than use this

bt if you want to add this view in all viewController than pass window in addView method

```
UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
[self addViewIn:window With:^(id sender) {

}];
```